# x = malloc(n * sizeof (int)); cannot convert void to int

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I found a code that computes the execution time of merge sort. I'm getting an error that says **"Cannot convert void to int"**. And I'm getting the error from the part of this code that says `x = malloc(n * sizeof (int));`

```
    x = malloc(n * sizeof (int));
```

Comment: C++ and C differ here. C++ has tighter rules about what can be converted to what. `void*` requires  cast to turn it into an `int*`. Why use `malloc` in C++, anyway? You should find `new` easier to use.

Comment: You should provide a [mcve]. Most of the code you posted is irrelevant. A three line program will do.

Comment: Now you're missing the declaration of `x`, which is kind of important.

Answer (score 2):

Since this question is tagged with C++, I recommend a completely different solution: Embrace the power of C++ and use a `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<int> descriptiveNameHere(n);
```

This approach frees you from having to manually manage the memory allocation. When the `vector` is allowed to go out of scope the storage will automatically be freed.

[Documentation on `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: While I certainly agree that in new code one should use `std::vector`
it doesn't answer the question, and might even be the wrong, since it is not known what happens later in the code. The newly allocated array could as well be passed to a function (which would then not compile) that takes ownership of the pointer and deletes it later (which would be a bug).

Comment: @GertWollny I know what's in the rest of the code; it's a C implementation of merge sort OP copied from somewhere that uses an unfortunate dialect of alphabet soup. Yes, OP would also have to modify another function to accept the `vector`, but I still see `vector` as preferable to `malloc` and `new`. Sometimes you have to go X-Y rather than provide a direct, but inferior, answer. We shouldn't be encouraging raw pointers, and especially not `malloc`. `malloc` serves a purpose. This ain't it.

Comment: The main reason this answer exists is none of the other answers even brought up `new` I stared with that, then stopped and thought, "What self-respecting programmer wouldn't use a `vector` here?"

Comment: it is nice that you know what specific code the OP is referring to, but for someone else trying to use some C code in a C++ project and hitting the same compiler error the answer is IMHO not very helpful, because one can not assume that  replacing a C-style array with a `std::vector` is always as simple.   The same goes for `new` because it requires one to replace `free` with `delete`or `delete[]`.

That said, of course any kind of automatic memory management is preferable over `malloc/free` and `std::vector` would be the natural choice.

Answer (score 1):

C++ compilers are more strict than C compilers. Therefore not all C code will compile using a C++ compiler, so you shouldn't use a C++ compiler if you are not using any C++ feature.

`malloc` returns a `void *` so you must cast it to the corresponding type, provided that you are using a C compiler:

```
Type * x = (Type *) malloc (sizeof(Type));
```

But if you must use C++ and malloc, then like mentioned in the comments, the C-style cast should be a last resort and you should rather use `static_cast`

```
Type * x = static_cast<Type *>(malloc(sizeof(Type)));
```

Comment: it works but now i got an error saying Lingking..\SOURCE\MERGY.EXE

Comment: @Leve Linker errors are tricky, you must provide more information

Comment: when i compiled it, there were no errors found and that was seen in the message panel

Comment: Using a C-style cast should be a last resort. Use a `static_cast`.

Comment: @Leve, you mean you saw this when you executed your program? then it must be expecting to find this exe but it's not finding it, maybe you should check in the link where you found the code

Answer (score 0):

You should cast the malloc like this.

```
x = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * n)
```

because malloc just return void pointer

Comment: They shouldn't use `malloc` in the first case. That or use a C compiler.

Comment: @jingbe it works but now i got an error saying Lingking..\SOURCE\MERGY.EXE

Comment: @Leve That error maybe because of compiler or developing tool. Try to reset the tool you use

Comment: C++ way: `x = new int[n];`. C++ way of casting: `x = reinterpret_cast<int*>(malloc([...]));`.